# Как с помощью стилей нарисовать полоски на seekbar?

Tags: java, android

Вот у меня есть такой `seekBar`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно поставить каким то образом в центре 2 полоски как своего рода границы центра как вот на скрине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если они статичные, оберните `SeekBar` в `RelativeLayout` и добавьте туда 3 `View` один как основной без бекграунда укажите для него атрибут

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

от которого 2 остальных которые будут с бекграундом (ваши полоски),  сделают отступы

примерно вот так

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <SeekBar
            .... />

        <View
                    android:layout_above="@+id/vDivider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="#0d00ff" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/vDivider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_below="@+id/vDivider"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#0d00ff" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

и как раз получиться так как у вас на рисунке